# Spring boot running in tomcat, required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, file-upload, tomcat9

I've spent the last 2 days in stack overflow reading solutions to this problem. I've tried all answers to other people's questions and nothing has worked for me. This works when I run spring boot via eclipse run as spring boot application but when I create the war and place it on tomcat I get the " Required request part 'file' is not present" error.

This is the article I was using as an example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Error:
`org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:logException(207): Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]`

Chrome network form data:

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Flow_Results.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

The file is present in the form being passed to web server.

Pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.location=${java.io.tmpdir}
```

Angular function making the post.

```
saveData(file: File, opertatorId: string): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    const newRequest = new HttpRequest('POST', 'cliareport/savedatafile/' + opertatorId, formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'text',
    });

    return this.httpClient.request(newRequest);
}
```

Spring boot controller

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
    return multipartResolver;
}

@PostMapping(path="/cliareport/savedatafile/{operatorid}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveDataFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    @PathVariable("operatorid") String operatorid) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that encounters this problem, it's a problem the NIO SSL Connector with the version tomcat that comes with the version of Ubuntu 20. To correct the issue upgrade your tomcat version.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat9/+bug/1903851